# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multimap’ with no type

Tags: c++, multimap

There seems to be a problem in the way that I am declaring my multimap:

```
std::multimap<int, std::string> table;
```

I keep getting the following error message and am quite stuck on how to solve this!

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multimap’ with no type
error: invalid use of ‘::’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

This is my first time trying multimap in C++, and I'm sorry if this seems a trivial problem. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

In my central.h I have the following code

```
class Central{
  private:
  int address;
  std::multimap<int, std::string> table;

public:
  Central(int _address);
```

In central.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#include "central.h"

Central::Central(int _address)
{
    address = _address;         
}
```

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: You need to include the header. Btw, nice pic

Comment: Thanks! ;D Thank you for your help. I've got it working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't `#include`d `<map>`. That's why the compiler thinks that multimap is a variable rather than a type.